# Laravel, phpunit : For loop not saving more than one entry in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I am developing an application using Laravel, Eloquent as ORM, phpunit for unit testing. I want to save more than one entry in database, i have tried for loop. But for loop is saving only one entry, even the loop is running only one time. The loop is working fine for other code except the save chunk. Below are my codes:

**Model Class:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = "posts";

    protected $fillable = [
            'id', 
            'user_id', 
            'title',
            'description',
            'total_needed',
            'total_collected', 
            'total_expanse',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'active',
            'updated_at',
            'created_at',
        ];

}
```

**Unit testing code**

```
class RepoPost extends TestCase
{
public function testMain()
    {
        echo "\n >----------- Test Name : " . get_class($this);
        echo "\n >----------- Test Main : ---------> \n";
        $this->postSave();
    } //test:main


public function postSave()
    {
        $postDummy = new Post();
        // $postDummy->id ='';
        $postDummy->user_id = 'Tst';
        $postDummy->title = 'Post Save Repo Test.';
        $postDummy->description = 'UnitTesting of URLs';
        $postDummy->total_needed = '2000';
        $postDummy->total_collected = '1000';
        $postDummy->total_expanse = '500';
        $postDummy->start_date = '22-09-2019';
        $postDummy->end_date = '22-10-2019';
        $postDummy->active = '1';
        $postDummy->updated_at = '2019-09-22';
        $postDummy->created_at = '2019-09-23';

        //loop 1
        for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
             echo '\n----PostSave----\n' . $x;
             $postRepoSave = $this->getRepoPostImpl();
             dd($postRepoSave->save2($postDummy));
         }

         //loop 2
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
            echo "\n The number is:" .  $x;
        }
    }


public function getRepoPostImpl()
    {
        return new Post_Repo_Impl;
    }


}
```

Loop 1 is saving only one data, the loop also running one time. Loop 2 is working well, printing 10 lines.

If i copy the same method multiple times in "testMain()", it is saving more than one entry, as many as times i have copied the method. Below code will save 3 entries in database.

```
    public function testMain()
        {
            echo "\n >----------- Test Name : " . get_class($
            $this->postSave();
            $this->postSave();
            $this->postSave();
        } //test:main
```

Using a loop in testMain(), also provide same result, saving one entry.

```
public function testMain()
    {
        echo "\n >----------- Test Name : " . get_class($this);
        for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
            $this->postSave();
        }
    } //test:main
```

**Repository code:**

```
class Post_Repo_Impl implements Post_Repo_I
{
    public function save2(Post $post)
    {
        $saveStatus = true;
        try {
            $post->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $saveStatus = false;
            error_log("Saveing Post Failed. : " . $e);
        }
        return $saveStatus;
    }
}
```

Why i am not able to save multiple entries by for loop, is there any way to do so?

**Update :**
instantiated the "post object" inside the loop, doesn't solve the issue.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
            $postDummy = new Post();
            // $postDummy->id ='';
            $postDummy->user_id = 'Tst';
            $postDummy->title = 'Post Save Repo Test.';
            $postDummy->description = 'UnitTesting of URLs';
            $postDummy->total_needed = '2000';
            $postDummy->total_collected = '1000';
            $postDummy->total_expanse = '500';
            $postDummy->start_date = '22-09-2019';
            $postDummy->end_date = '22-10-2019';
            $postDummy->active = '1';
            $postDummy->updated_at = '2019-09-22';
            $postDummy->created_at = '2019-09-22';

            echo '\n----PostSave----\n' . $x;
            $postRepoSave = $this->getRepoPostImpl();
            dd($postRepoSave->save2($postDummy));

        }
```

Comment: Add the `getRepoPostImpl()` function code to your question please

Comment: @CaddyDZ please check

Comment: Updated my answer to include everything and tested it myself so it's 100% working now

Answer (score 1):

Move the Model instantiation inside the for loop, and clean up your test, it's calling an external class implementing an interface for no purpose

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Post;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RepoPostTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function testMain()
    {
        echo "\n >----------- Test Name : " . get_class($this);
        echo "\n >----------- Test Main : ---------> \n";
        for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
            echo '\n----PostSave----\n' . $x;
            $this->postSave();
        }
        $this->assertCount(10, Post::whereTime('created_at', now())->get());
    }

    public function postSave()
    {
        $postDummy = new Post();
        $postDummy->user_id = 'Tst';
        $postDummy->title = 'Post Save Repo Test.';
        $postDummy->description = 'UnitTesting of URLs';
        $postDummy->total_needed = '2000';
        $postDummy->total_collected = '1000';
        $postDummy->total_expanse = '500';
        $postDummy->start_date = '22-09-2019';
        $postDummy->end_date = '22-10-2019';
        $postDummy->active = '1';
        $postDummy->save();
    }
}
```

Assuming a `posts` migration like this

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('total_needed');
    $table->string('total_collected');
    $table->string('total_expanse');
    $table->string('start_date');
    $table->string('end_date');
    $table->string('active');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And you don't need the `$table` property on your model because it has the plural form so it's automatically resolved, and you don't need the `$fillable` property because you're not doing mass assignment

#### Results

```
PHPUnit 8.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)
 >----------- Test Name : Tests\Feature\RepoPostTest
 >----------- Test Main : ---------> 
\n----PostSave----\n0\n----PostSave----\n1\n----PostSave----\n2\n----PostSave----\n3\n----PostSave----\n4\n----PostSave----\n5\n----PostSave----\n6\n----PostSave----\n7\n----PostSave----\n8\n----PostSave----\n9

Time: 263 ms, Memory: 20.00 MB

OK (1 tests, 1 assertions)
```